# Why every web site coder doesn't use DNT?

Tags: cookies, tracking, do-not-track

I am a coder who codes html, css and js. Also, I am an internet surfer.

A lot of webpages ask me "can I collect your data?" with pop-ups. Then, I have to dismiss them every time. In my webpage, I follow browser [DNT(DO NOT TRACK)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/DNT) setting. However, why everybody doesn't?

DNT is easy to call, just `console.log(navigator.doNotTrack);`.